# Create a new empty file from linux command line with same permissions and ownership?

Tags: linux, file, command-line

I need to create a new empty file with the same permissions and ownership (group and user) as the source, kind of like how cp -p FILE1 FILE1.bak works but without actually copying the contents.

I know I can empty out the contents later on, but that seems wasteful.

I cant use a script - the solution must run from the command line directly.

Comment: Write a C program using the `stat` and `chmod` system calls?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
touch newfile
chmod `stat -c %a originalfile` newfile
chown `stat -c %U originalfile`:`stat -c %G originalfile` newfile
```

Comment: And drop these into a shell function so that you can execute it "from the command line directly".

Comment: But didn't he tell he "can't use a script" (I didn't understood why)?

Comment: I think "chown \`stat -c %U originalfile\` newfile" should be "chown \`stat -c %U originalfile\`:\`stat -c %G originalfile\` newfile" or "chgrp \`stat -c %G originalfile\` newfile" after chown. In the current solution group permissions are not being considered

Comment: Hi - can you revise your answer to include chgrp `stat -c %G originalfile` newfile

Comment: Hi Māris - why did you remove the access permissions copying?

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
touch newfile
chmod --reference=oldfile newfile
chown --reference=oldfile newfile
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cp --attributes-only --preserve=ownership
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the touch command.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utouch.htm